# Comparators in std::map, std::set and std::priority_queue

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, move-semantics, functor

All these three containers accept a function object by const reference as opposed to either a value or a forwarding reference.  This results in the need for copying the function object into the container's internal storage (at most twice).

Is there a reason for copying a function object twice?  As opposed to giving the user the ability to pass any type of function object and have that be constructed into the internal functor storage?  That way the library is more general and there are less surprises to the user.

---

The same philosophy is applied in `push_back()` functions - they have two overloads, one with a const reference and one with an rvalue reference, because this gives the user more control about whether they want to move the value or copy the value.  The library remains efficient in the general case without making any assumptions about the usecase.

I suspect this is a design decision that has been carried over since the pre-C++11 days.  Would changing this be a decent proposal for the standard?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the comparator is a pretty small object that is cheap to copy, and you're only going to construct your container once. That extra one copy one time isn't *really* going to matter. You're probably not creating a bunch of `std::map`s in your latency sensitive code. So there's simply not a lot of benefit from introducing more constructors for these containers. And what would such a proposal look like? Would you then want to take the `Allocator` by rvalue reference as well? Now we're adding a bunch more constructors. Change all the constructors taking a `Compare const&` to instead take a constrained forwarding references? Now, we broke ABI for still marginal, if any, gain. Constructors are complicated. I'm not even convinced that if `std::map` were designed today, the interface would look different in this regard. If anything, we'd probably just take `Compare` by value instead of by `const&`.

On the other hand, `push_back` is used a LOT, with a wide variety of types, during the main runtime of programs. Being able to move into a `vector`, or `emplace` into a `vector`, is a huge win. The two situations aren't really comparable.

Comment: Why then does the std::thread constructor accept a functor by rvalue reference if it is only going to copy it internally?  And we will not be adding more constructors, it will just be changing an existing constructor to accept a parameter by forwarding reference.  Although I am not sure if that would break things..

Comment: @Curious `thread` has one constructor that takes an arbitrary function. `map` has like 4 constructors that take a `Compare` or an `Allocator` - you'd have to change all of them, which is way more complex, and breaks ABI.

Comment: How exactly does that break ABI?  When you pass a non rvalue, the comparator will just be copied as before.

Comment: Unless it wasn't const. Or you didn't provide an allocator, now that one isn't const either.

Comment: If it wasn't const it still is just going to be copied right?  It will only be moved if it was an rvalue

Comment: @Curious Yeah but the signature of the constructor would be different.